# 100% height of a DIV inside a DIV. Why is this not working?

Tags: css, html, height

i know, this is an old question but i can't get this to work...

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/NLRqM/2/

i want to have the "#main_rechts" DIV to be 100% height inside of "#main"... (automatically the same height as the green box)!

thanks so much!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: He's trying to get 2 side by side `div` with the same dynamic height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#main-rechts` is floated so it will not work. Try playing with `display: table` and `display: table-cell` CSS properties, but please note that they will not work in IE 7 and lower.

I've updated your fiddle to show what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/Pharaon/NLRqM/5/

Answer (score 1):

Try to give them both a `min-height: 200px;` (or any other value fitting your design):

```
#main_links {
  width:680px;
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  background-color:#096;
  min-height:200px;
}
#main_rechts {
  width:260px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  background-color:#e7e8e8;
  min-height:200px;
}
```

Comment: That's the worst solution. That won't work anymore with a 200px+ height

Answer (score 0):

set some fixed height to `#main` and add `height:100%` to `#main_rechts`

Answer (score 0):

You `#main` has no fixed height do you want to have 100% of what? :) Set some fixed height to `#main`